# Compare Date format with String using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am comparing strings with date oracle using the following sql but I am getting incorrect results.
I tried with to_date, to_char options but didn't get any proper result.

```
select order from table where Date1 <>  to_char(Date2, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI');
```

where Date1 : 10-JUN-21 01.00.00.000000000 AM
Date2:  10-JUN-2021 01:00

The above sql returns the rows for above mentioned Date1 and Date2 although it is equal.
Also Date1 is varchar format and Date2 is TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE  format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table and data:

> Date1 is varchar format and Date2 is TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE format.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  date1 VARCHAR2(20),
  date2 TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO table_name (
  date1,
  date2
) VALUES (
  '10-JUN-2021 01:00',
  TIMESTAMP '2021-06-10 01:00:00.000000'
);
```

You can convert `DATE1` to a `TIMESTAMP` and compare:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_TIMESTAMP( Date1, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ) <> Date2;
```

Or, convert `DATE2` to a string:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Date1 <> TO_CHAR( Date2, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' );
```

Which both output zero rows:

> | DATE1 | DATE2 |
> | --- | --- |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8526faea080e095a86c5df504cdd6d81)*

Comment: Hi, I analyzed more and found my Date1 is 10-JUN-2021 01:00:00 instead of 10-JUN-2021 01:00 and for which first query SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Date1 <> TO_CHAR( Date2, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ); will return rows. Also for second query the result is ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

Comment: @user2907032 Then add `:SS` to the format model when you convert to/from a string.